# apt-get vs aptitude

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [aptitude vs. apt-get: what is the recommended (aka the “right”) tool to use actually?](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-what-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use-actua)

What is the difference between apt-get vs aptitude. Which one is better? pros/cons?

Comment: `$ apt-get moo`

Comment: s/b on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aptitude` is a front-end to APT (Advanced Packaging Tool). It is smarter at resolving dependencies, will install packages markt as recommended by default and is currently recommended to upgrade distributions.

Furthermore, `aptitude` can be used with a menu driven interface, while it also provides a commandline interface similiar (but more powerful) then `apt-get` alone.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, aptitude is menu-driven, while apt-get is purely CLI. In other words, with aptitude, you can browse through categories and see what packages are available to install or uninstall, while with apt-get, you need to know the exact name of the packages you're installing or uninstalling.

As for pros and cons, it's all about preference. apt-get is certainly a lot faster if you know what you want, but if you're more familiar with menus, aptitude is for you.

Comment: Then how do you explain `aptitude install XXX` or `aptitude update` or `aptitude dist-upgrade`?

Comment: As others have said, aptitude is a front-end to APT, so it uses the same command line arguments as apt-get. I generally use apt-get for my package updating needs and have only used aptitude sans arguments, so I wasn't previously aware it could be used in a similar fashion to apt-get.

Comment: No, aptitude are distinct command-line front ends, and the fact that they have many (by no means all) similar command line arguments is due to developer convergence and not to code sharing.

Comment: I think it's become painfully obvious to everyone involved how little I know about aptitude.